Discrete LQR problem with LMI (solved using MATLAB)
I am trying to solve an LMI problem given in Page 265 in this book (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-09393-2). I have 3 LMI constraints Eq. (6.66), (6.67) and (6.68) and objective is to minimize $\delta$ given a constant delay $h$ and $\epsilon$. I am using Sedumi solver in MATLAB and trying to solve Example 6.3. Given below is the screenshot of the LMI given in the book.
https://i.sstatic.net/m6ZsRBDs.jpg
Here is the MATLAB code:
% Problem parameters
A = [1.06, 0.1; 0, 0.74];
B = [0; 1];
L = sqrt(0.1) * [1, 0; 0, 1; 0, 0];
D = sqrt(0.1) * [0; 0; 1];
x0 = [1; 0];
epsilon = 1;
h = 3;

% Define variables
n = size(A, 1);
m = size(B, 2);
P = sdpvar(n, n, 'symmetric');
P2 = sdpvar(n, n, 'symmetric');
R = sdpvar(n, n, 'symmetric');
S = sdpvar(n, n, 'symmetric');
S12 = sdpvar(n, n, 'full');
Y = sdpvar(m, n, 'full');
delta = sdpvar(1,1);

% Positive definiteness constraints
constraints = [P >= 0, R >= 0, P2>= 0, S >= 0, delta>=0];

% LMI block
LMI = [((A-eye(n))*P2 + P2'*(A-eye(n))'+S-R), (P-P2+epsilon*P2'*(A-eye(n))'), S12, B*Y+R-S12, L';
       (P-P2+epsilon*P2'*(A-eye(n))')', (P-epsilon*P2-epsilon*P2' +h*h*R), zeros(n), epsilon*B*Y, zeros(size(L'));
       S12', zeros(n), -(S+R), R- S12', zeros(size(L'));
       (B*Y+R-S12)', (epsilon*B*Y)', (R-S12')', -2*R+S12+S12', Y'*D';
       L, zeros(size(L)), zeros(size(L)), (Y'*D')', -eye(size(L, 1))];

constraints = [constraints, LMI <= 0];

% Additional LMIs
constraints = [constraints, [R, S12; S12', R] >= 0];
constraints = [constraints, [-delta, x0'; x0, -P2-P2'+P+h*S] <= 0];

% Solve the problem
%options = sdpsettings('solver', 'sedumi', 'verbose', 1);
options = sdpsettings('solver', 'sdpt3', 'verbose', 1);

diagnostics = solvesdp(constraints, delta, options);
check(constraints)

I am getting numerically infeasible solution using Sedumi solver. Some of my constraints have negative primal residual. I tried scaling the matrices but it didn't work. From the book, I know the solution should be $K=[-0.403 -0.126]$.
I do not have any idea how to solve this issue and I have tried multiple solvers. Any help or hint is greatly appreciated.
